# What definition of encapsulation is correct?

Tags: java, oop

when I read some documents they stated that:

1. Encapsulation is a way of combining both data members and member functions, which operate on those data members, into a single unit
2. Encapsulation is minimizing the interdependence between classes and it is typically implemented through information hiding.
   Encapsulation can help to create more maintainable code by helping to prevent the ripple effect of code changes.
   It also helps with creating loosely coupled code by reducing direct access to an object's state and behavior.

```
private String time;

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
```

Lets say I decided to use a String to keep track of time.
After awhile, I come to realize that an int representing seconds might be a better data type for time.
Not only must I change the data type in the object, but also every time I referenced the object's time in the entire program!

```
private int time;

public int getTime() {
    return time;
}
```

when I use getter, it doesn't reach the idea of ​​definition 2

Comment: Wikipedia defines it pretty well: [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) --- Basically, it's both, though some people only use option 2 as the definition.

Comment: @andreas  Using private and getter is one way of doing encapsulation,
when I change the data type how can I implement this principle:
"Encapsulation can help to create more maintainable code by helping to prevent the ripple effect of code changes."

Comment: By not changing the method return type. E.g. by keeping `String getTime()` and adding `int getTimeAsInt()`, all existing code will continue to function without modification, i.e. no ripple effect. Also known as keeping the code backwards-compatible.

Comment: For more complex cases like changing from list to tree,
I think this is very difficult to do,
Maybe with data potentially changing in the future, I need to redesign so that Users will depend on the interface, not the data. 
E.g. private List<Account> accounts; => private IAccount accounts;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a `Time` class, and for simplicity of this example, let's say we only want precision to the minute, i.e. HH:MM. Un-encapsulated, that would be:

```java
class Time {
    public int hour;
    public int minute;
}
```

Encapsulation is then done for one or more of the following reasons.

#### Restricting access, aka validation

We don't want public access to those fields, because then we can't ensure that the values are valid (0-23 and 0-59, respectively).

So we encapsulate:

```java
class Time {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    public int getHour() {
        return this.hour;
    }
    public int getMinute() {
        return this.minute;
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) {
        if (hour < 0 || hour > 23)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hour: " + hour + " (must be 0-23)");
        this.hour = hour;
    }
    public void setMinute(int minute) {
        if (minute < 0 || minute > 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid minute: " + minute + " (must be 0-59)");
        this.minute = minute;
    }
```

#### Information bundling

Even though data is stored as `hour` and `minute`, we can enforce that values are *given* together.

```java
class Time {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    public int getHour() {
        return this.hour;
    }
    public int getMinute() {
        return this.minute;
    }

    public void setTime(int hour, int minute) {
        if (hour < 0 || hour > 23)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hour: " + hour + " (must be 0-23)");
        if (minute < 0 || minute > 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid minute: " + minute + " (must be 0-59)");
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
    }
```

This is especially useful when the data is co-dependent, e.g. for a `Date` class, the `day` value's range depend on the `month` value, as well as the `year` value when determining the valid range of February.

#### Information hiding

If we encapsulate, we can later decide to change the internals to store the values differently, e.g. we can decide to store value as minute-of-day.

```java
class Time {
    private int minuteOfDay;

    public int getHour() {
        return this.minuteOfDay / 60;
    }
    public int getMinute() {
        return this.minuteOfDay % 60;
    }

    public int setHour(int hour) {
        setTime(hour, getMinute());
    }
    public int setMinute(int minute) {
        setTime(getHour(), minute);
    }
    public void setTime(int hour, int minute) {
        if (hour < 0 || hour > 23)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hour: " + hour + " (must be 0-23)");
        if (minute < 0 || minute > 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid minute: " + minute + " (must be 0-59)");
        this.minuteOfDay = hour * 60 + minute;
    }
```

As can be seen, the encapsulation ensured that nothing has changed as seen from the outside.